# Android list View with 2 activity

Tags: android

How can I add two activity with image and text in a list one after another
like "vchat" application.

I prepare two activity with image and text but I don't know how to add them in one list one after another.

Comment: Do you want to include Image and text in listview rows.?

Comment: i want to make a app like vchat, that include send and received sms in ,but i don't know how add send and received sms(that include text and image) to one list view, one after another..